Who are the "our" in Mark 12:29?
Does Jesus belong to the pronoun "our" in Mark 12:29?
Mark 12:29 Literal Standard Version

And Jesus answered him, “The first of all the commands—Hear, O Israel:
The LORD is our God, the LORD is one;

Was there anything in the scribe's and the people included in the word "our" understanding that the Lord their God included another person other than the LORD/YHWH?

I do not see any reason that Jesus would be excluded from being included in the possessive pronoun "our" in Mark 12:29, for the following reasons

Jesus was speaking and so, grammatically, He is automatically included
Jesus, in other places calls the Father "God" such as:


Mark 15:34 - And at the ninth hour Jesus cried with a loud voice, “Eloi, Eloi, lema sabachthani?” which means, “My [Jesus'] God, my God, why have you forsaken me?”  See also Matt 27:46.
John 20:17 - “Do not cling to Me,” Jesus said, “for I have not yet ascended to the Father. But go and tell My brothers, ‘I am ascending to My Father and your Father, to My [Jesus'] God and your God.’ ”
Heb 10:7 - Then I [Jesus] said, ‘Here I am, it is written about Me in the scroll: I have come to do Your will, O God.’ ”
Rev 3:2 - Wake up and strengthen what remains, which was about to die; for I have found your deeds incomplete in the sight of My [Jesus'] God.
Rev 3:12 - The one who conquers, I will make him a pillar in the temple of my God. Never shall he go out of it, and I will write on him the name of my [Jesus'] God, and the name of the city of my God, the new Jerusalem, which comes down from my God out of heaven, and my own new name.
etc (this is not an exhaustive list)

However, and this is significant - The Father also calls Jesus God:

Heb 1:8, 9 - But about the Son He [the Father] says:
“Your throne, O God, endures forever and ever, and justice is the
scepter of Your kingdom. You have loved righteousness and hated
wickedness; therefore God, Your God, has anointed You above Your
companions with the oil of joy.”

Notice that the Father addresses Jesus as "God" and Jesus addresses the Father as "God".  This is the mutuality of love.  Indeed, in the next verse (Heb 1:10) the author quotes Ps 102 and addresses Jesus as Jehovah.  This is consistent with many other passages (oft quoted by me in this space) that address Jesus as God in the NT such as John 20:28, Matt 1:23, John 1:18, Phil 2:5-8, Titus 2:13, etc.
Jesus neatly summarized this situation when He said:

John 10:30, “I and the Father are one.”  (Compare Deut 6:4.)


In this passage, Jesus answers a question put to him:

One of the scribes, when he came forward and heard them disputing and
saw how well he had answered them, asked him, “Which is the first of
all the commandments?” 29 Jesus replied, “The first is this: ‘Hear, O
Israel! The Lord our God, the LORD is one!"

This is not a theological statement, but an answer to the question as to which is the greatest commandment. The first commandment is to hear God, with the implication that "hearing" is also obeying. The commandment applies to Jesus was well as to other Jews, and he was exemplary in practicing it, even to the point of death.
Hebrews 5

8 Son though he was, he learned obedience from what he suffered; 9
and when he was made perfect, he became the source of eternal
salvation for all who obey him, 10 declared by God high priest
according to the order of Melchizedek.

So yes, in speaking of "our God," Jesus included himself. Trinitarian theology does not normally subsume Jesus' humanity in his divinity. (The Son possesses two natures - human and divine - which are not "mixed" or "confused.") Being fully human and a faithful Jew, Jesus recognized, heard and obeyed Yawheh as his God.

Can you please elaborate the two natures that you say the son possesses? By "not subsuming his humanity with his divinity" does it mean that that "his divinity " does different from his humanity? If being fully human, Jesus recognized, heard and obeyed YHWH as his God, does his divinity also recognize, hear and obey YHWH?

Alex Balilo - This is  a good summary of the traditional viewpoint: "The historic Christian understanding of the person of Christ is that He is one person who possesses two natures: a divine nature and a human nature. Each nature retains its unique properties, and the two natures remain distinct, though inseparably united in Christ's person."

Thank you for the link. The link doesn't answer whether Jesus' divinity does different from his humanity. It does not answer whether his divinity also recognize, hear and obey YHWH. I can't find a verse where Jesus stated that his human self did something and divine self did something.

The First Commandment, as recorded in Exodus 20:1-3 goes:

And God spoke all these words:
2 “I am the Lord your God, who brought you out of Egypt, out of the land of slavery.3 “You shall have no other gods before[a] me.

Those Commandments were given to Israel through Moses. In Mark 12;28, Jesus is quoting the Commandment as if it was falling from the mouth of Moses. Here, the usage ' our' includes both the Israel and Moses who obtained the Commandments for them.   That fact is clear from the punctuation marks appearing in NIV :

" The most important one,” answered Jesus, “is this: ‘Hear, O Israel: The Lord our God, the Lord is one.[e] 30 Love the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your mind and with all your strength.’  ... ..

< Such a way of quoting of the Commandments can be traced to Malachi 4:4 (KJV) :

Remember ye the law of Moses my servant, which I commanded unto him in Horeb for all Israel, with the statutes and judgments.

